# My Mac signed app opens with "identity cannot be confirmed"

Tags: xcode, macos, codesign

I have written a Mac OSX app (MyApp.app), but when I distribute it, users get a pop-up message:

`“MyApp” can’t be opened because the identity of the developer cannot be confirmed.`

So I got an Apple Developer ID, signed it with [`codesign`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/codesign.1.html) as it is not an Xcode app, and that should theoretically fix it according to:
https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev1cc22a95c

When I follow the instructions the signing seems to be confirmed:

```
$ spctl -a -v MyApp.app
MyApp.app: accepted
source=Developer ID
```

But when I then open it:

```
$ open MyApp.app
```

I get the same message instead of the message according to the help. My security settings are on `Allow app downloaded from: App Store and identified developers`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the command with all arguments you're using for `codesign`?

Comment: Hi @spartygw, it's been a while since I posted this and I'm afraid I can't recall, sorry. I do agree that I should have included it in the original post.

Comment: Hey, no problem @Tim. I was just stumbled on this and thought I might be able to help with more info. Take care.